# как скопировать базу данных при отключённом mysql сервере

Tags: mysql, база-данных, openserver

Использую OpenServer по непонятным причинам переастал подключаться сервер MySql выбрал в модуле другой сервер Mysql всё подключилось однако в данном варианте базы данных в ней нет моих баз. 
Вопрос как мне скопировать базы данных на опенс сервре при отключённом сервере Mysql где хранятся базы данных?

Comment: `/openserver/userdata/mysql*/`

Comment: Да копировал файлы из папки одного варианта базы данных в другую но новый сервер их не распознаёт

Comment: 1) "Новый" сервер должен быть строго той же версии 2) Копировать следует весь каталог @@datadir, а также используемый .ini-файл.

Comment: @Akina Сервер у меня той же версии, но не совсем понял 
1. Копировать следует весь католог - Вы имеете ввиду каталог с базой данных или же полностю содержимое сервера 2. Неподскажите где .ini-файл найти?

Comment: Сделайте на работающем сервере `select @@datadir;` и посмотрите, что там находится. Вот всё то же следует притащить со сдохшего сервера. Также найдите на старом сервере ини-файл (обычно он лежит вне указанного каталога, рядом с ним) и тоже перетащите, и укажите явно в строке запуска сервера.

Comment: @Akina спасибо сейчас буду пробовать